# why is the opening price of a stock sometimes different when you are working with 5 minute candles and 1 day candles?

Tags: trading, price

Take a look at apple on tradingview. On the 6 of May, the opening price of apple with 1-day candles is $204.29, however, when I look at the opening price with 5-minute candles, the opening price was $204.17. In my theory, the opening price should be the same when working with 1 day, 1 hour and 5-minute candles, it shouldn't matter. I've seen this with different stocks.

So my question is, how can this be explained?

I hope someone can give me some insight into this, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one opening price for regular trading  hours.  It doesn't matter what the time length of the first bar or candle of the day is.  It's still the same opening price.  This is provider error.

FWIW, I subscribe to data from Thomson Reuters and they show the opening trade as $204.29

Comment: Seems like the right answer to me.